# Canonical Partners update problem

Tags: canonical, boot-partition

I enabled canonical partners in software&updates and when it updated it saved everything into /boot partition which has only ~200MB and I can't see the partition now but remember making it when installing Ubuntu 14.04. So my question is if I can change the partition/folder/place that software and updates want to save stuff in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can try to clean some downloaded packages by running commands

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

It looks like you mix up / and /boot directories. Software is not installed into /boot directory. But it could run out of place because of kernel image and headers update. You can remove old kernels by using synaptic.

Generally speaking it is not a good idea to make a separate /boot partition. This has no benefits for desktop computers, but may cause problems like you have.

There is no good way to keep kernel images anywhere ele, but /boot. I suggest to merge /boot with /, but it is not quite easy for a novice. Maybe it makes sense to reinstall the system, keeping your /home partition. I guess you have it separate. You can remove /boot partiton and increase / in gparted. You can do it after booting from LiveCD.

Comment: Thanks. I have a laptop and when I was installing Ubuntu making a /boot was (recommended) and I had problems with booting Ubuntu previously without a /boot. I would rather not have to go through all that horrible work again just to fail to boot Ubuntu again.

I did the 'autoclean' and now I didn't get a error message. But when I tried to type in Terminal

sudo apt-get clean

I had to enter my password. Which wasn't possible. I hit all the buttons but nothing was being typed. But the autoclean wasn't pasword protected so that worked.

Comment: It was never officially recomended to do a separate /boot partitions. Some people write this in forums for some reason. Passwords in terminal do not appear. Just type it. But you will have this problem again soon after some kernel updates. And it won't be fixed by clean. So think.

Comment: Can you steer me in a direction where I can find a good guide on how to merge '/boot' partition with '/'? Much appreciated.

Comment: I can't give a link to a guide. But you can boot from Ubuntu LiveCD (flash drive you installed from),  then run gparted. There you can delete boot partition and resize your / partition. Then install Ubuntu again. There must be some installation guides.